Proving $\sum_{i = b}^{a+b-1}\binom{i-1}{b-1}\cdot i\cdot 2^{b+a-i} = 2\cdot b\cdot \sum_{i = b+1}^{a+b} \binom{i-1}{b} \cdot 2^{b+a-i}$
Dear Math stackexchange community,
I recently stumbled across the following binomial identity when working on a combinatoric project:
$$\sum_{i = b}^{a+b-1}\binom{i-1}{b-1}\cdot i\cdot 2^{b+a-i} = 2\cdot b\cdot \sum_{i = b+1}^{a+b} \binom{i-1}{b} \cdot 2^{b+a-i}$$
$b$, $a$ are natural numbers $>0$
which according to my limited tests seems to be true. But I couldn't prove it. At first I tried to just write the sum out and look for patterns which didn't work. Then I tried to prove it with a sign inversing involution but I failed to find a Bijection...
Help would be greatly appreciated

Try letting $j=i+1$ and writing the LHS in terms of $j$ rather than $i$, and then manipulate it to look like the RHS

This is just the standard "absorption identity"
$$\begin{align}
n \binom{n-1}{m} &= \frac{n(n-1)!}{m! \, (n-1-m)!} \\
&= \frac{n!}{m! \, (n-(m+1))!} \\
&= \frac{ (m+1) n!}{(m+1)! \, (n - (m+1))!} \\
&= (m+1) \binom{n}{m+1},
\end{align}$$
followed by an index shift.
